# Fluttermap: Is there any way to make a polygon fill as an image?

Tags: flutter, dart, polygon, fill, fluttermap

I'm new to flutter.
I want to make a mobile application where flags of countries will be shown as polygons.
That is, the boundaries of the polygons will be the boundaries of countries, and the country flags will be used as a fill, something like this (see picture)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/29dxi.jpg)

I searched on the Internet how this could be done.
However, I didn't find anything other than color fill...
Please help me, I will be very grateful :)

Comment: This unfortunately isn't supported. You'll have to create your own layer and canvas, or use a widget placing plugin like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_polywidget and clip as necessary.